# HTML/CSS Element lose its position in other computers but not in mine

Tags: css

I'm not sure if the resolution of the screen can affect the CSS. My screen resolution is 1280 x 1024.

Last time, I tried my website: http://alexchen.co.nr/ in a friends's laptop and my webpage and an element (I think is `#lang`) moved out of place (i think it only happened in Chrome).

*In my computer everything is fine (Firefox, Chrome, IE6, 7 , 8, etc.)*

CSS (I'm also using [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)):

```
/* tags */
body {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #666;
    font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h2 {
    color: #DDD;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
h3 {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
p {
    line-height: 160%;
}
a {
    /*color: #0AE;*/
    color: #08B;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #044;
}
/* structure */
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}
/* header */
#header {
}
#header h1 {
    padding: 190px 20px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header h1 a {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 216px;
    height: 28px;
}
/* banner */
#lang {
    float: right;
    padding: 202px 0 0 0;
}
#lang li {
    float: left;
}
#lang li a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#lang li.current a {
    color: #666;
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
/* intro */
#banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}
#banner h3 a {
    font-size: 28px;
}
#logo {
    background-color: #222;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 169px;
    width: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
    height: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
}
#logo2 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #DDD);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#DDD));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#DDDDDD');
    background-color: #DDD;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 169px;
    width: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
    height: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
}
#logo3 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #DDD);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#DDD));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#DDDDDD');
    background-color: #DDD;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 169px;
    width: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
    height: 240px; /* ie6 hack */
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    padding: 200px 0 0 40px;
}
#nav li {
        float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #08B;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav li.current a {
    color: #888;
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#tagline {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    width: 540px; /* 560 */
}
#tagline h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* work */
#content {
    color: #888;
}
.showcase {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px; /* ie hack */
}
.first {
    background: #222;
    display: inline; /* ie6 hack */
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}
.first h3, .first p {
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pusher {
    background: #333;
    display: inline; /* ie6 hack */
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}
.blank-pusher {
    background: #DDD;
    display: inline; /* ie6 hack */
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}
.pusher h3 {
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 120px 20px 10px;
}
.pusher p {
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.nopic {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.pic {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pic:hover {
    opacity: 0.1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 10);
}
#fancybox-outer {
    height: 100% !important;
}
#fancybox-inner {
    height: 100% !important;
}
#inline1, #inline2, #inline3, #inline4, #inline5, #inline6, #inline7, #inline8 {
    width: 680px;
}
#inline1 img, #inline2 img, #inline3 img, #inline4 img, #inline5 img, #inline6 img, #inline7 img, #inline8 img {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

(continues...)

**Normal display:**

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/9638/normale.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/9638/normale.png)

**Abnormal display:**

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/2846/notnormal.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/2846/notnormal.png)

I think I in my friend's laptop the horizontal width, padding or margin of some elements was duplicated or something.

I made the text inside `#lang` a bit smaller, but not sure if the problem still there.

**Is my webpage: http://alexchen.co.nr/ displaying correctly in your current screen resolution (IE, Firefox and Chrome)?**

If not how do I fix it? what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too see what your site looks like for different machines, OSs, and browsers, check out http://browsershots.org/.

I just submitted a job [here](http://browsershots.org/http://alexchen.co.nr/). Your site loads very slowly (try [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) to see how you can speed it up) so some browsers will time out before it finishes and you'll see a blank screen.

Try to find out your friend's precise OS, browser type, and browser version. If he's on Chrome 4 and you're on Chrome 5, for instance, results can be different.

Comment: I'm not sure if my images are too heavy, but my free hosting is already slow. thanks for the tip!